# Install Ubuntu 14.04 over 11.10 from CD OR USB

Tags: upgrade, 14.04

In my laptop I have first installed Windows 7. Then, installed Ubuntu 11.10. Now my laptop contains two Operating Systems. I don't have internet connectivity in home. But I have Ubuntu 14.04 ISO with me,

**i need to upgrade Ubuntu 11.10 with Ubuntu 14.04 without uninstalling Windows 7 and Ubuntu 11.10**

. How to achieve this...

please help..am new one to Ubuntu.

Comment: I have 320GB HDD, and 3GB memory in my laptop with 15 inch monitor. I think, it is possible to install Ubuntu 14.04 with this configuration after checking the link.

Comment: Your systems requirements are OK to upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04. An upgrade like that is hard to do, so backup all your personal files before you start the upgrade, and don't rule out the option of doing a clean install of Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know it is possible only to upgrade from one version to the next or from LTS to LTS. In your case that would be from 11.10 to 12.04 and then from 12.04 to 14.04. 
If you have only 14.04 available you can write it to a bootable USB and boot from it. At some point during installing, before you can do any "damage" to your existing configuration you will be asked how do you want to install (e.g. alongside Ubuntu 11.10 and Win or erase Ubuntu 11.10, etc). This is the place to check: if you find the option to Upgrade 11.10 to 14.04 you're in luck. If not, you have to backup your data and do a clean install.

Comment: I would suggest always backing up your data on a regular basis and always before doing a version upgrade on your operating system. Your answer would be improved by beginning by protecting the users data IMHO.

Comment: @ElderGeek You are absolutely right, thank you for your observation.